# How to compute complex vectors' inner product using cublas or thrust?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, gpu

After searching a long time, I still can't solve this problem.

I have two vectors: x = [a1,...,aN], y = [b1,...,bN].

And I want to compute their inner product:  = a1*conj(b1) + ... + aN*conj(bN). (conj(.) means the complex conjugate operation)

I have tried cublasCdotu, and it just computes a1*b1 + ... + aN*bN.

And cublasCdotc returns conj(a1)*conj(b1) + ... + conj(aN)*conj(bN).

Finally, I tried thrust::inner_product, and it computes a1*b1 + ... + aN*bN too.

My thrust code is like the following:

```
typedef thrust::complex<float> comThr;
thrust::host_vector< comThr > x( vec_size );
thrust::generate(x.begin(), x.end(), rand);

thrust::host_vector< comThr > y( vec_size );
thrust::generate(y.begin(), y.end(), rand);
comThr z = thrust::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), comThr(0.0f,0.0f) );
```

Could you give me some advice on this problem? Thank you!

Comment: use `thrust::transform_reduce`

Comment: if you're not in the mood for thrust and if your codebase is already "mathy" enough to support it with basically zero cost, you could do a cublasCgemm and conjugate transpose your b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `thrust::inner_product`. All that is required is a user defined binary function which implements `a * conj(b)`, where `conj` is the complex conjugate. The thrust library includes all the complex operators required, so the implementation is a simple as an operator like this:

```
  __host__ __device__
  comThr operator()(comThr a, comThr b) 
  { 
    return  a * thrust::conj(b); 
  };
```

A complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "thrust/host_vector.h"
#include "thrust/functional.h"
#include "thrust/complex.h"
#include "thrust/inner_product.h"
#include "thrust/random.h"

typedef thrust::complex<float> comThr;

struct a_dot_conj_b : public thrust::binary_function<comThr,comThr,comThr>
{
  __host__ __device__
  comThr operator()(comThr a, comThr b) 
  { 
    return  a * thrust::conj(b); 
  };
};

__host__ static __inline__ comThr rand_comThr()
{
    return comThr((float)rand()/RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
}

int main()
{
    const int vec_size = 16;

    thrust::host_vector< comThr > x( vec_size );
    thrust::generate(x.begin(), x.end(), rand_comThr);

    thrust::host_vector< comThr > y( vec_size );
    thrust::generate(y.begin(), y.end(), rand_comThr);

    comThr z = thrust::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), comThr(0.0f,0.0f),
                                     thrust::plus<comThr>(),  a_dot_conj_b());

    comThr zref(0.0,0.0);
    for(int i=0; i<vec_size; i++) {
        comThr val = x[i] * thrust::conj(y[i]);
        std::cout << i << " " << x[i] << " op " << y[i] << " = " << val  << std::endl;
        zref += val;
    }

    std::cout << "z = " << z << " zref = " << zref << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which will compile and run like so:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o dotprod_thrust dotprod_thrust.cu 

$ ./dotprod_thrust 

0 (0.394383,0.840188) op (0.296032,0.61264) = (0.631482,0.00710744)
1 (0.79844,0.783099) op (0.524287,0.637552) = (0.917879,-0.0984784)
2 (0.197551,0.911647) op (0.972775,0.493583) = (0.642147,0.78932)
3 (0.76823,0.335223) op (0.771358,0.292517) = (0.690638,0.0338566)
4 (0.55397,0.277775) op (0.769914,0.526745) = (0.572826,-0.0779383)
5 (0.628871,0.477397) op (0.891529,0.400229) = (0.751725,0.173921)
6 (0.513401,0.364784) op (0.352458,0.283315) = (0.284301,-0.0168827)
7 (0.916195,0.95223) op (0.919026,0.807725) = (1.61115,0.135091)
8 (0.717297,0.635712) op (0.949327,0.0697553) = (0.725294,0.553463)
9 (0.606969,0.141603) op (0.0860558,0.525995) = (0.126716,-0.307077)
10 (0.242887,0.0163006) op (0.663227,0.192214) = (0.164222,-0.0358752)
11 (0.804177,0.137232) op (0.348893,0.890233) = (0.40274,-0.668025)
12 (0.400944,0.156679) op (0.020023,0.0641713) = (0.0180824,-0.0225919)
13 (0.108809,0.12979) op (0.0630958,0.457702) = (0.0662707,-0.0416127)
14 (0.218257,0.998924) op (0.970634,0.23828) = (0.449871,0.917584)
15 (0.839112,0.512932) op (0.85092,0.902208) = (1.17679,-0.32059)
z = (9.23213,1.02127) zref = (9.23213,1.02127)
```

Comment: Nice example. See here for the documentation on thrust::inner_product, including different overloads: https://nvidia.github.io/thrust/api/groups/group__transformed__reductions.html